# Automatically adjust view width when other views' constraints change

Tags: ios, user-interface, uiview, autolayout

I'm trying to define constraints in AutoLayout which would automatically resize a view when another one changes.

There are two views side by side and I would like for the right one to grow only by simply making the left one thinner (and not directly changing the right-side-view's width constraint).
I'm asking whether this can be done with clever use of constraints.

The change need not be animated.

This is all the code in the app:

```
class ViewController: UIViewController {

    var view1 = UIView()
    var view2 = UIView()
    var h1Constraints: [AnyObject]?
    var h2Constraints: [AnyObject]?
    var v1Constraints: [AnyObject]?
    var v2Constraints: [AnyObject]?

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        // Boilerplate
        view1.backgroundColor = UIColor.redColor()
        view2.backgroundColor = UIColor.greenColor()
        view2.addGestureRecognizer(UITapGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: "grow"))
        view1.setTranslatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints(false)
        view2.setTranslatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints(false)
        view.addSubview(view1)
        view.addSubview(view2)


        // Constraints
        let views = ["view1":view1, "view2": view2]
        let metrics = ["halfScreenWidth":view.frame.size.width/2, "screenHeight":view.frame.size.height]

        h1Constraints = NSLayoutConstraint.constraintsWithVisualFormat("H:|[view1(>=halfScreenWidth)]->=0-|", options: NSLayoutFormatOptions(0), metrics: metrics, views: views)
        h2Constraints = NSLayoutConstraint.constraintsWithVisualFormat("H:|->=0-[view2(>=halfScreenWidth)]|", options: NSLayoutFormatOptions(0), metrics: metrics, views: views)

        v1Constraints = NSLayoutConstraint.constraintsWithVisualFormat("V:|[view1(screenHeight)]", options: NSLayoutFormatOptions(0), metrics: metrics, views: views)
        v2Constraints = NSLayoutConstraint.constraintsWithVisualFormat("V:|[view2(screenHeight)]", options: NSLayoutFormatOptions(0), metrics: metrics, views: views)

        view.addConstraints(h1Constraints!)
        view.addConstraints(h2Constraints!)
        view.addConstraints(v1Constraints!)
        view.addConstraints(v2Constraints!)
    }


    @objc func grow() {
        for var index = 0; index < h1Constraints?.count; ++index {
            var constraint = h1Constraints![index] as! NSLayoutConstraint
            if constraint.firstAttribute == .Width {
                constraint.constant = 20
            }
        }
        self.view.layoutIfNeeded()
    }
}
```

I'm simply trying to tell the layout engine that the views are both **greater than, or equal to** half of the screen width, while having an adjustable margin **(greater than, or equal to 0)**.

This way, when I change the left-side-view's width to 20, I thought that the right-side-view would grow, since it has a >= width declared.

This does not work. While the left side shrinks, the right side stays the way it is.

[image: This is what happens, but shouldn't]

**Can that sort of relation be achieved with Auto Layout?**

---

**EDIT:**

As per @luk2302 's answer, the solution was the following:

```
// Constraints
let views = ["view1":view1, "view2": view2]
let metrics = ["halfScreenWidth":view.frame.size.width/2, "screenHeight":view.frame.size.height]

h1Constraints = NSLayoutConstraint.constraintsWithVisualFormat("H:|[view1(>=halfScreenWidth)][view2(>=halfScreenWidth)]|", options: NSLayoutFormatOptions(0), metrics: metrics, views: views)

v1Constraints = NSLayoutConstraint.constraintsWithVisualFormat("V:|[view1(screenHeight)]", options: NSLayoutFormatOptions(0), metrics: metrics, views: views)
v2Constraints = NSLayoutConstraint.constraintsWithVisualFormat("V:|[view2(screenHeight)]", options: NSLayoutFormatOptions(0), metrics: metrics, views: views)

view.addConstraints(h1Constraints!)
view.addConstraints(v1Constraints!)
view.addConstraints(v2Constraints!)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes it can be achieved if I understand your requirement correctly. I recommend the following constraints:

- align the left of the left view to the left of the screen/superview
- align the right of the right view to the right of the screen/superview
- align the right of the left view with the left of the right view.
- add a constraint for the width of the left view

Then you can change the constant value of the last constraint and everything should behave as desired.

Note that I have never tried creating constraints by code, only using the IB - but this would be the way I would do it there.